# find the mongodb document if a key-value paired is matched from nested document using node red function node

Tags: mongodb, node-red

i have a mongodb collection named "Device_Records", using node-red i would like to extract all the documents that satisfy a mongo query.Till now i used mongodb node , drag and drop the mongo node and select "find" from the operation selector. But this does not work  when the document is of a nested document.
 [image: here is the screenshort]
 more over i want to use msg.operation in the node-red function node so that i can write dynamic query.
i would like to get all the documents that match "device_id":66 from  this collection.since Condition is a key which is a array of objets,am confused about the query :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#embedded-documents) in your query: `{ 'Condition.device_id': 66 }`:

[image]

Comment: Great to hear! I'd appreciate if you'd mark this answer as the solution :)